# Using lambda function in a foreach over controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, lambda

I would like to translate this:

```
foreach(Control c in Controls)
{
    if(c is TextBox)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Into:

```
foreach(Control c => (c is TextBox) in Controls)
{
    // ...
}
```

How can it be done using the lambda function specifically?

Comment: So, basicly, you want all Controls that are Textboxes?

Comment: @Jerodev basicly yes

Comment: @PatricHofman this is not a duplicate, since the question contains the supposed duplicate answer in itself, real question is not how to get all the textboxes, but how to translate this loop

Comment: @Ernis Sometimes most voted answer is a _"Answer"_.

Comment: @Ernis The answers given below are exactly the answers given in the duplicate, so the dup is okay.

Comment: no, I specifically asked to use the lambda function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And use this:

```
foreach (var control in Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c is TextBox))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: 'Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where', how can i fix it?

Comment: This answer is invalid. It does not work.

Comment: using System.Linq

Comment: No, there is no `Where`, since `Controls` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: It does not work anyway

Comment: Just use `OfType`. It spares you a lot of unnecessary calls @Donnoh

Comment: thanks for fixing it

Answer (score 8):

Use [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (TextBox c in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{

}
```

> It filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Also don't forget to add [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) to your `using` directives first:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
foreach(TextBox ctrlTxtBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
   // Got it code here
}
```

[`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Comment: Too late.......

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yep always, That's why I keep this name..! Got a call before hit post.

Comment: That happens all the time :)

Comment: @un-lucky seems you name fits quite nicely :D

Comment: @LonelyNeuron: yes definitely,

Comment: Just because ti's a duplicate answer is no reason to down vote.  If it was there would be a ton of answers that need down votes on this site.

Comment: Tell the one who is downvoting... @juharr. You know such comments are not very likely to help anything. On the other hand, there is no use in posting the exact same answer minutes later.

Comment: @un-lucky You are a good answerer. Check your reputation. Also your answer is correct. +1.

Comment: @juharr: It's always depends on individual's decision, Sometimes you may get 10+ votes for a duplicate question, that all depends